# How to read nested JSON in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have been following the instructions here: 
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html to retrieve a value from a json file.
I have managed to read the top level value of my json content - however I cannot see how to read the value of a nested tag e.g. using this file ...

```
{
"glossary":{
  "title":"example glossary",
  "GlossDiv":{
     "title":"S",
     "GlossList":{
        "GlossEntry":{
           "ID":"SGML",
           "SortAs":"SGML",
           "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
           "Acronym":"SGML",
           "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
           "GlossDef":{
              "para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
              "GlossSeeAlso":[
                 "GML",
                 "XML"
              ]
           },
           "GlossSee":"markup"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Please can someone show me how to get to the value of "para" above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After parsing your json data based on [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html#file-jsonparsingsample-java-L1), you can use `Result` to read deep into the json content:

```
import com.codename1.processing.Result;

...

Map<String, Object> data = json.parseJSON(r);
Result result = Result.fromContent(data);
String id = result.getAsString("glossary/GlossDiv/GlossList/GlossEntry/ID");
String para = result.getAsString("glossary/GlossDiv/GlossList/GlossEntry/GlossDef/para");
```