# How to loop though nested JSON data in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

This is related to this question

[How to read nested JSON in Codename One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441538/how-to-read-nested-json-in-codename-one)

( I don't know if you're supposed to edit and existing question ??? )

So thanks to the answer to that question I now know how to retrieve the specific tag value that I need, but unfortunately it does not work if the data loops ... for example

How would I get the looping values of "para" from this code?

```
{  
  "glossary":{  
  "title":"example glossary",
  "GlossDiv":{  
     "title":"S",
     "GlossList":{  
        "GlossEntry":{  
           "ID":"SGML1",
           "SortAs":"SGML1",
           "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
           "Acronym":"SGML1",
           "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
           "GlossDef":{  
              "para":"para1",
              "GlossSeeAlso":[  
                 "GML",
                 "XML"
              ]
           },
           "GlossSee":"markup"
        },
        "GlossEntry":{  
           "ID":"SGML2",
           "SortAs":"SGML2",
           "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
           "Acronym":"SGML2",
           "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
           "GlossDef":{  
              "para":"para2",
              "GlossSeeAlso":[  
                 "GML",
                 "XML"
              ]
           },
           "GlossSee":"markup"
        },
        "GlossEntry":{  
           "ID":"SGML3",
           "SortAs":"SGML3",
           "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language",
           "Acronym":"SGML3",
           "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986",
           "GlossDef":{  
              "para":"para3",
              "GlossSeeAlso":[  
                 "GML",
                 "XML"
              ]
           },
           "GlossSee":"markup"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Again - any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the pattern of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441538/how-to-read-nested-json-in-codename-one/46441831#46441831) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441538/how-to-read-nested-json-in-codename-one), you can do this:

```
String path = "glossary/GlossDiv/GlossList"

int size = result.getSizeOfArray(path);
if (size > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String para = result.getAsString(path + "[" + i + "]/GlossEntry/GlossDef/para");
        System.out.println(para);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again :-)